# UISearchController searchBar text overlapping content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I need some help for this issue:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
_searchController.delegate = self;
_searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
_searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
_searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
_searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
_searchController.searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(20.0, 0.0);
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Is there any of you who are experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Also post the code itself. It'll be better for understanding

Comment: Thanks bro, already

Comment: Have you tried to remove `_searchController.searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(20.0, 0.0);` (or just to comment it ?)

Comment: when i remove that, the text content overlap with search icon bro @Dean